# When merging two arrays, the first array gets shorter by 1

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, security, password-protection

I have a password which I hash with SHA256. Then I have a salt which looks like that:

**AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==**

At the end of the process both of them are byte-arrays which I then merge into a new byte-array.

My **PROBLEM** is that while merging the password with the salt, my hashed password gets shorter by one character at the end.

**Expected output:**

uIxnpgdBQpSPJrqwYucIOeyOyqyCv7HbBfd74ovoxjI=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==

**Output:**

uIxnpgdBQpSPJrqwYucIOeyOyqyCv7HbBfd74ovoxjIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==

As you can see there is a **=** missing after the **l**.

My Method:

```
public static byte[] HashPassword(byte[] passwordToHash)
{
    byte[] hInput;
    byte[] hSalt = GetSalt();
    using(SHA256 sh = SHA256.Create())
    {
        hInput = sh.ComputeHash(passwordToHash);
    }
    byte[] SaltedPw = new byte[(hInput.Length+ 1 ) + (hSalt.Length + 3)];
    Array.Copy(hInput,0, SaltedPw, 0,hInput.Length);
    Array.Copy(hSalt, 0, SaltedPw, hInput.Length, hSalt.Length);
    return SaltedPw;
}

public static byte[] GetSalt()
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    return salt;
}
```

How can I prevent the shortening of my password?

Comment: In the second Array.Copy it should be hInput.Length+1

Comment: It still takes away the "=" of my hashed password

Comment: @kelalaka: no, I shouldn't be `hInput.Length+1`, since the index range of the first part is `0..Length - 1`, `Length` is automatically the start index of the second part.

Comment: What I've tried is to add + 1 to hInput.Length in the first Copy but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You are not showing us how you are converting the strings to byte arrays. I suspect the error to be there. Btw., why are these `+1` and `+3` for the lengths? The salt you are showing us has a length of 24 characters.

Comment: If you're Base64 encoding the concatenated byte array, you will *never* get an `=` in the middle of the result, Base64 only adds `=` to the end of the string in order to act as padding if the original input was has a length that's not a multiple of 3. If you can Base64 decode the result and get back the correct original input then it would seem everything is working correctly.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes without the +1 and +3 the salt would be missing the two "=" at the end of the salt.

Comment: No, because your byte arrays already contain everything they need to contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You must not add the salt to the hashed password. You must add the salt to the plain password and then hash. The point is to make the hash of a current or short password unrecognizable.

The base 64 encoding is only applied to the final result to allow storing the password hash as string. Therefore, you will never have to merge base 64 strings. Base 64 strings are padded with `=` at the end to get a length which is a multiple of 4. Therefore you will never see a `=` in the middle.

```
public static string GetHashedPassword(string plainPassword, byte[] salt)
{
    byte[] passwordBytes = GetBytes(plainPassword);

    // Merge the password bytes and the salt bytes
    var mergedBytes = new byte[passwordBytes.Length + salt.Length];
    Array.Copy(passwordBytes, mergedBytes, passwordBytes.Length);
    Array.Copy(salt, 0, mergedBytes, passwordBytes.Length, salt.Length);

    // Now hash password + salt
    byte[] hash;
    using (var sha = SHA256.Create()) {
        hash = sha.ComputeHash(mergedBytes);
    }
    return Base64Encode(hash);
}
```

You will also need this:

```
public static string Base64Encode(byte[] bytes)
{
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}

static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Create random salt bytes for each password and store the salt as a separate piece of information together with the hashed password. Like this, every password gets a different salt. This makes [Pre-computed dictionary attack/Rainbow table attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack#Pre-computed_dictionary_attack/Rainbow_table_attack) infeasible. The salt does not need to be encrypted. You probably will want to store it as base 64 string as well. To get the salt bytes again you will need `Convert.FromBase64String()`.